# How to configure JAAS on JBoss?

Tags: jboss

Im having a problem with "Failed to load users/passwords/role files: java.io.IOException: No properties file: users.properties or defaults: defaultUsers.properties found" error from jboss. No matter what I change in conf/login-config.xml always that same error.
Turning on TRACE for org.jboss.security shows that it does Security domain: myapp followed by findResource: null and the above error.

Ive tryed adding a users.properties to my .war WEB-INF/classes/users.properties to no avail.

Why is jBoss doing like this? What is this JAAS and why does it need it? 
What does it require, where to put what files, if its possible Ill remove all of this org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule completly, just let me use my app.

Thanks